# Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I have add into my project's libralies the andriod-support-v4.jar... but I am getting this error:

```
Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method org.secure.sms.SmsReceiver.showNotification
 Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder', referenced from method org.secure.sms.SmsReceiver.createNotification
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder
    at org.secure.sms.SmsReceiver.createNotification(SmsReceiver.java:108)
    at org.secure.sms.SmsReceiver.onReceive(SmsReceiver.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where is the problem??

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I95ke.jpg

Comment: Did you add this import? **import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;**

Comment: No, just android-support-v4.jar from extra forlder inside android SDK. Where is this import? to add it?

Comment: At the top of your activity, among the other import statements, add that import manually (as I wrote it in bold)

Comment: A! Sorry. I have it. Yes...

Comment: And this? **import android.app.NotificationManager;**

Comment: Yes. I have all these import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

Comment: Please refer to [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Answer (score 1):

be sure to have `android-support-v4.jar` inside your folder `/libs`
and add this to your class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```