# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support,v4.app.Notification

Tags: java, android, eclipse, notifications

Following a reboot my Eclipse Android project was damaged, with the vast majority of my import statements being removed. I've managed to recover it using the "Source...Organize Imports" option, but now I get the above error in a previously-working piece of code which uses NotificationCompat.

I found and followed the advice from this question:
[Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887816/could-not-find-class-android-app-notificationbuilder)

I have import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat; at the top of my class, and have both  android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in the lib folder of my project. I still get the error above however.

What else can I try to resolve this?

Comment: What exactly is the class the compiler is complaining about? Have you cleaned your project?

Comment: Do you add this libraries to Build Path?

Comment: Compat$Builder is the problem, and the support libs are in my build path. I've tried cleaning the project but no luck. I've just seem another thread that has suggested adding External JARs as an alternative to having the support library in my lib folder, so will try that.